# Animate CSS div to a fixed position

Tags: css

This code takes a ball and moves it to the right and back again. How can I get it to move to the right, and stay there?

http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/pBCax

You can fiddle with a Live version of the output there.

```
body {
padding: 30px;
}

#animate {
position: absolute;
top: 100px;
left: 30px;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 border-radius: 50%;
background: red;

animation: move 3s ease infinite;
 }

@keyframes move {
  50% {
 top: 200px;
 left: 130px;
 }
}
```

The css code says 'infinite' and when I delete that, it moves the ball to the right, and then back to where it was one time. I'd like it to move to the right, and just stay there.

Comment: When I remove infinite, the ball floats to the right, and back to where it was one time. I'dl like it to float to the right and just stay there one time, Update ahead

Comment: I see... I added a more complete answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `infinite` with `forwards` and add a `from` and `to` to your `@keyframes`

Adjust the `top`, `left` values as necessary.

See below:

```css
body {
  padding: 30px;
}
#animate {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: red;
  animation: move 3s ease forwards;
}
@keyframes move {
  from {
    top: 0px;
    left: 10px;
  }
  to {
    top: 200px;
    left: 130px;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Animate with Top/Left</h1>

<div id="animate"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
 animation: move 3s ease forwards;
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yebvZx

You can read about the `animation-fill-mode` property here:
https://drafts.csswg.org/css-animations-1/#animation-fill-mode

> **forwards** -
>   After the animation ends (as determined by its animation-iteration-count), the animation will apply the property values for the time the animation ended.

Comment: @icebear Great. Don't forget to upvote and accept my answer if it helped :)

Comment: @icebear :-/ Why did you accept ochi's answer over mine? I was there first and his answer added an unnecessary step. Oh well :(

Answer (score 1):

Your are looking for:

```
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
```